# Revit API : SaveAsCloudModel failing with exception : Cloud model Entitlement

Tags: api, revit-api, autodesk

One one particular BIM360 hub the API: Autodesk.Revit.DB.Document: SaveAsCloudModel(Guid accountId, Guid projectId, string folderId, string modelName) throws the exception:
You do not have cloud model entitlement to access this resource in cloud. Many other hubs call this without any issues.

The user can manually save to the same exact bim360 project/folder combination with the same file on the same machine.

The rights were checked in the manage.autodesk.com as BIM Collaborate Pro for the user and admin rights to all projects.

The ids are correct. In the journal, before the api call: Utility.getEntitlement: The entitlement is Skyscraper is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue privately, but append the details here to help others.

Actually, the user has Skyscraper (workshared cloud model) entitlement, but the user doesn't have Single user entitlement.

The user created a non-workshare cloud model and wanted  to convert it workshared cloud model, but it failed at the 1st step to save the non-worksharing model because he did not have Single user entitlement .

The suggestion is:
Enable worksharing locally (like he enable a worksharing in revit local file);
Call saveAsCloudModel API.